# Showing that $F=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\langle-y,x\rangle$ is not path independent.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative

I thought that path independence and being conservative were tied together so using $\displaystyle F=\left\langle{\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}}\right\rangle$ I found $\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \dfrac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2-y^2)^2}$ and then $\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \dfrac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2-y^2)^2}$, also. But they're the same so that means its is conservative, which doesn't show that it's not path independent. Put them into symbolab to be sure I wasn't making a mistake doing the partial derivatives and got the same.

Comment: What about $(x, y) = (0, 0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the line integral around the unit circle. Observe
\begin{align}
\oint_C F\cdot ds = \int^{2\pi}_0 (-\sin t, \cos t)\cdot (-\sin t, \cos t)\ dt= \int^{2\pi}_0 \ dt = 2\pi
\end{align}
which means $F$ is not a conservative vector field, i.e. not path independent.

Note: I used the parametrization $c(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. So because you have the circle thing with the $x^2+y^2$ then you can't just do it the normal way?

Comment: @windy401 You only need one counterexample to prove $F$ is not conservative. If by the "normal way" you mean by checking equality of partials, the problem is that the partials are not continuous.

Comment: Ohhh. Ok. That's why you can't do it that way. Forgot that they had to be. Thanks.

Comment: @windy401 You actually *could* do it that way; you'd prove or disprove that that discontinuity in the derivatives is removable. If the discontinuity *is* removable you'd check if you could piecewise-define $F$ and its partials to "fix" things. In this case Jacky_Chong's approach of finding a counter-example is easier.